# how to create two dimensional array for pushing the values of different rectangles

Tags: javascript, arrays, svg

I want to push the values of different rectangles to two dimensional array.I have pushed the values based on the svg rect id.but this code is not working.
can you please suggest me.Thanks in advance.

Here is my code.

```
    this.model.selectedData = l;
    var name = this.svgObject.id + '_selectRect'+this.selectedRectIndex;
    var m=this.selectedRectIndex;               
    this.model.rectCollection[m][name]=(this.model.selectedData);
```

I have push the first rectangle data that is pushed in rectcollection array.when pushing the second rectangle data,this exception thrown.
0x800a138f - JavaScript runtime error: Unable to set property 'container_svg_selectRect1' of undefined or null reference

anyone suggest me how to use array concept for this scenario.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You changed the question so that it matched the answer and basically asked another question. That's not allowed as it makes the answer look like nonsense and is unfair to the answerer. If you've a follow up question you should ask it separately. I've returned your question to its original state.

Answer (score 1):

```
this.model.selectedData = l;
var name = this.svgObject.id + '_selectRect'+this.selectedRectIndex;
var m=this.selectedRectIndex;

//** define as object **
this.model.rectCollection[m] = {};

this.model.rectCollection[m][name]=(this.model.selectedData);
```

Comment: thanks for ur reply.i want to know another thing.shall we can use array collection as below format     this.model.rectCollection[name] = {};

           this.model.rectCollection[name][m] = (this.model.selectedData);

Comment: It might be best to ask another question for that.